# How can I keep my southern facing bedroom cool in the Arizona Heat?

Tags: hvac

Our MB is on the South side of our house in AZ. It stays warmer than the rest of the house. I am considering installing and 8" in-line booster fan at the 'T' where the supply duct (flexible) where it branches off to the 2 supply registers.

Two questions:

1. Would this be the proper alternative?
2. Can I tap off of the 110 VAC to the blower motor so that the booster fan would only run when the blower runs?

So, I guess there is really a third question: Will it matter if the booster fan runs when the supply fan is off?

Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: plant trees to provide shade

Comment: Have you thought about installing a mini-split in the MBR. They are great for giving your ac or heat an extra boost in a single room.

Comment: What do you have for a furnace? Can you post its wiring diagram?

Comment: Do you have a ceiling fan in the bedroom?

Comment: I would suggest a mini split, quiet efficient and no duct work to mess with there are even full diy models out there no hvac tech required.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately this is a second story so trees are out. I have considered a mini-split so maybe I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

The 1 time I used an in-line fan as you are suggesting it made more noise than it was worth. It produced very little increase in air flow.

I would have an HVAC company look at your problem to see if there was a simple fix or as the others have said plant trees, and some type of shading or add a separate cooling device. Since you are in Arizona, could you add a "swamp cooler" just for that room?

Comment: Consider awnings above the south facing windows